# Can't connect custom msg to publisher and subscriber

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. So, I created custom .msg and tested it with not_composable.cpp simple publisher and subscriber that was taken from [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/foxy/rclcpp/topics) in separate package and project has successfully builded. After that I used same CMakeLists.txt and package.xml comands and used them in my original  package and I have following error:

```
By not providing "Findminicar_control.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "minicar_control", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "minicar_control"
  with any of the following names:

    minicar_controlConfig.cmake
    minicar_control-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "minicar_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "minicar_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "minicar_control" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
```

Where minicar_control is package that contains my .msg files and in this package I create publisher and subscriber.
This method works normally with my test package. .msg was created using [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/408930/undefiend-reference-to-custom-msg-from-publisher-and-subscriber/) guide and added to package with commands that are shown in this duide.
Appreciate any help and suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408936/can%27t-connect-custom-msg-to-publisher-and-subscriber./) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-05**:
I am sorry, but are the publisher and the `.msg` files in the same package? If yes, then you need a few changes in `CMakeLists.txt` file as shown in the following question: #q402196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Link that @ravijoshi provided is solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help

---

Originally posted by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) with karma: 95 on 2022-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0